# Access data from AuthorizeCore in Controller ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize-attribute

I am validating user from different group [BASIC, MANAGER, ADMIN] in AuthorizeCore

> ```
> In AuthorizeCore, check user exists in 3 groups.
> ```

If user is found then based on the group want to provide add/edit/delete permission in view.

how can I implement this? how to pass data back to controller from AuthorizeCore? Please suggest me.

Comment: You don't.  Instead, you should use roles to validate users belong in a group, then use User.IsInRole() to determine if the user has the rights to do something.